# Azure app function: best approach for this scenario

Tags: sql, azure-functions

I’m developing a small game where the player owns droids used to perform some automated actions. The easiest example is giving an order to a droid to send him at a specific position. Basically, the users gives it a position and the droid goes there. I’m already using a lot Azure app function and I’d like to use them to make the droid moves.

On the top of my head, I thought about making one function that would trigger every minute, fetch all the droid that need to move then make them move.

The issue with this approach is that if the game is popular, there could be hundreds of droids and I have to ensure that the function execution time stays below the minute.

I thought about just retrieving all droids that needs to move then for each of them calling a Azure app function via its URL to make it execute for this particular droid. In my head, it would parallelize the execution a bit but I’m not sure I’m correct.

I also have to think about using sql transaction or not in order to be sure not to create deadlocks.

The final question would be « how to handle recurring treatment of potentially large amount of data and ensure that it stays below the minute ? »

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you handle such scenarios with queues. Each order becomes a queue message, and then Azure Function is triggered by it and processes the order. It can and will scale based on the amount of messages in the queue.

If your logic still requires timer-based processing, the timer should be as lean as possible, e.g. send the queue messages to a queue which would do the real work.

Comment: The issue is that it could be that the queue become so big that two executions for the same droid are handled with an interval bigger than one minute. However I don’t see a magic solution here... I guess that’s why you said that the core must be as lean as possible.